# Improper integral with two parameters

Tags: calculus, analysis, improper-integrals

I have to investigate convergence of integral $\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln^q{x}}{(x^2-p)\sqrt{x^2+3}}dx$.
For $p<1$ integral converges. For $p=1$, after substitution $t=x-1$, integral can be written as sum of two integrals, with bounds from 0 to 1 and from 1 to infinity. First integral converges for $q>0$ and second converges, therefore, in this case we have convergence for $q>0$. I would like to know what happens when p>1?
Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The integral starts at $0$ or at $1$? If ar $1$ there is no spliiting needed.

Comment: Is the lower limit of your integral actually $0$? As it is currently written, it doesn't make sense to write the integral as the sum $\int_{0}^{1}+\int_{1}^{\infty}$.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc The integral starts with 1, but then I use substitution t=x-1 to get integral from 0 to infinity.

Comment: @SangchulLee Lower limit is 0 when substitution t=x-1 is used for case p=1.

Comment: For $p>1$ you get the factor $(x-p^{1/2})$ in the denominator, so the integral $\int\limits_{1+\delta}^{p^{1/2}}$ is divergent, for $1+\delta <p^{1/2}.$